# Clickable datapoints that launches closeable modal window in d3 chart (nvd3)

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

First of all I want to thank the community here your the help I've received.

I'm building a custom version of the example here http://nvd3.org/ghpages/scatter.html

Is there a way to make each circle be a clickable link? and then when you click the link, have a modal popup that appears originating from the circle? with a close button on the modal.

I know that sounds complicated but I'm just having a hard time navigating that NVD3 library, has it been deprecated/abandoned? I cannot find any documentation on it. I've read Scott Murray's guide but it seems like the NVD3 library has been heavily modified, most of what I read from Scott Murray isn't really applying in this example.

my example page is here http://goo.gl/pUKW9 and the code i have is....

```
<div id="offsetDiv">
  <div id="test1" class="chartWrap">
    <svg></svg>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
//Format A
var chart;

nv.addGraph(function() {
  chart = nv.models.scatterChart()
                .showDistX(true)
                .showDistY(true)
                //.height(500)
                .useVoronoi(true)
                .color(d3.scale.category10().range());

  chart.xAxis.tickFormat(d3.format('.02f'))
  chart.yAxis.tickFormat(d3.format('.02f'))

  d3.select('#test1 svg')
      .datum(randomData(4,40))
    .transition().duration(500)
      .call(chart)


  nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

  chart.dispatch.on('stateChange', function(e) { nv.log('New State:', JSON.stringify(e)); });

  return chart;
});


function randomData(groups, points) { //# groups,# points per group
var data = [
{key: 'Weak Guidance', values: [
{x: 1, y: 1}
, {x: 2, y: 3}
, {x: 4, y: 9    }]},

{key: 'Strong Guidance', values: [
{x: 32, y: 0}
, {x: 3, y: 54}
, {x: 1, y: 8}  ]              }];

  return data;
}


</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if nvd3 provides any functionality to attach handlers to elements (I think it doesn't), but you can do this quite easily in "pure" d3. The code would look something like

```
svg.selectAll("circle").on("click", function(d, i) { ... });
```

where `svg` is a reference to the container element of the graph. You might have to be more specific in the selector, e.g. add a specific class (`selectAll("circle.myclass")`).

Neither d3 nor nvd3 provide any functionality for modal dialogs. You should be able to use something like [jQuery dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) without problems though. The code that creates the dialog goes inside the event handler function.

Comment: It sounds like what you want to do would require quite extensive modifications/additions to nvd3, so this might be a good idea. There's quite a learning curve though :)

Comment: Thanks lars, and to get the cursor to also change during the onhover (to let the user know it is clickable), does that also mean chaining together an onhover event? or would that .on("click", ... )   cover that?

Comment: For that it should be to set the cursor style with e.g. `.style("cursor", "pointer")`.

Comment: in your example    
`svg.selectAll("circle").on("click", function(d, i) { ... });`  
I ended up doing a test run like so,  

 `svg.selectAll("circle").on("click", function(d, i) { alert( $(this).text() ); });`  
 
not working but i believe it has to do with the d,i part, originally i thought that meant domain and input (correspending to each x and y of the circles), so i replaced with d with cx and i with cy, like so  

 `svg.selectAll("circle").on("click", function(cx, cy) { alert( $(this).text() ); });`  

but that does not appear to be working either, any ideas?

Comment: `d` is the data element bound to the circle in this case and `i` is the index. When you say "not working", what do you mean?